# Restrict a class to be instantiated not more than five times

Tags: java, exception, object

I want to create maximum five objects of a class. If more than times object are created it will throw an exception. Please help.

Comment: Smells like very, very bad design.

Comment: Check for the Singleton/Multipleton pattern. In short, make the constructor private and then create a static method to serve instances. BTW, throwing an exception when more than 5 objects are created doesn't sound a good idea...

Comment: Also known as a multipleton.

Comment: Are you sure it will always be 5 forever? What if you want 7 after a few months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think would be the solution for this kind of question. We need to have private static counter and once it reaches the desire limit then throw an exception.

```
class Program
{
    private static int instanceCount;

    public Program()
    {
        if (instanceCount > 5)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Only 5 instances of Program are allowed");
        instanceCount++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
            new Program();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: This is *probably* fine: I believe that `int` is an **atomic** type in Java. Perhaps my solution is overkill.

Answer (score 5):

Create a static factory method that keeps track of the instances created.

With a private constructor, the users have to use the factory method, which can then throw the exception if more than 5 objects have already been created.

Comment: One could do the same with an ordinary constructor and some static instance counter.

Comment: True, but this gives the opportunity to actually return an existing instance instead (although the OP did specify that he wants an exception, but maybe he'll change his mind).

Answer (score 3):

Do something like this:

```
public class VeryOddClass
{
    private static final Object lock = new Object();
    private static int s_count;

    static
    {
         s_count = 5; /*ToDo - read from configuration*/
    }

    public VeryOddClass()
    {
        synchronize(lock){            
            if (s_count <= 0) throw new VeryOddClassException();
            --s_count;
        }
        /*normality resumes from here*/
```

But do rethink your design requirements.

Answer (score 0):

make a static private field and increment it in the constructor. Also, check there for the count. Increment it by TheClassname.field++ or something and check by TheClassname.field==5

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate your class via a factory and limit it to 5 instances using a simple counter. Or use a modified Singleton:
[OOPS (Design Patterns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323814/oops-design-patterns)